# Two domains pointing two the same content by mistake. Google search results not showing the right one on the first position

Tags: google, google-search

By mistake, at this moment I have two domains pointing to the same content.

[www.todocamino.info](http://www.todocamino.info)
[www.mytravelbanners.com](http://www.mytravelbanners.com)

The problem: when I search on Google "mytravelbanners" I get the URL www.todocamino.info at the first position.

How to make the Google search results show www.mytravelbanners.com? Of course www.mytravelbanners.com is also indexed on Google Search.

I know I should not point www.todocamino to the same content as my www.mytravelbanners.com but I made a mistake. Before fixing the mistake, I would like to know if it is possible to show on Google search results www.mytravelbanners.com at the first position instead of www.todocamino.info

Im not getting the same issue on other search engines like Yahoo: when I search "mytravelbanners", the first position if for www.mytravelbanners.com

Comment: Fix the mistake and Google will get it right within a couple weeks of recrawling.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks, but two weeks is too much for my client :). I know I can fix the error just not pointing www.todocamino.info to MyTravelBanners content, but now I need to keep www.todocamino.info showing the MyTravelBanners since if someone search "mytravelbanners" on Google www.todocamino.info is shown at the first position.

Comment: Assuming that most URLs aren't the same between the two, you should put redirects in place for any URLs that would go 404 with the site pointing to the correct content.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller sorry, I didn't understand, could expand your comment or give me additional information (link, etc)?

Comment: You cannot fix this quickly. Sorry. You are stuck with the results for a while. Fix the problem. From there, you can use Google Search Console to Fetch as Google and then Submit to Index your most important pages. This can still take 1-2 days for the regular googlebot to effect a change. There is a limit to this option, so I recommend paying attention to those pages that users find in search most often. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix it is to 301 redirect the incorrect URLs from the error site to the correct site. You need to make a list of all the URLs on mytravelbanners.com and add them as redirects to the *.htaccess* file for todocomino.info:

```
redirect permanent /anuncios-gratis-categoria/empleos http://www.mytravelbanners.com/anuncios-gratis-categoria/empleos 
redirect permanent /anuncio/oferta-de-prestamo-de-dinero-entre-particular-48h-rapido-y-fiable-emilio-pablo98-gmail-com http://www.mytravelbanners.com/anuncio/oferta-de-prestamo-de-dinero-entre-particular-48h-rapido-y-fiable-emilio-pablo98-gmail-com
...
```

This may be a very long list.   If the directories don't also exist on the error site, you could simplify this by just redirecting the directories which will also redirect each of their pages individually.

```
redirect permanent /anuncios-gratis-categoria/ http://www.mytravelbanners.com/anuncios-gratis-categoria/
redirect permanent /anuncio/ http://www.mytravelbanners.com/anuncio/
...
```

Then your list of redirects will be much smaller.

With these redirects in place you can safely put up the correct content for the error site.

1. Your users coming from Google search will be redirected to the correct place.   The only pages for which it won't work will be ones where both sites have the same page URL, such as the home page.
2. Googlebot will crawl the error site, get the redirect and update the search index.

It may take Google several weeks to fix the search results.  In the meantime it won't hurt the site or users because users will get properly redirected.